# How to pass Map arguments to javascript function in Flutter Web?

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart

I am trying to encrypt a credit card of PagSeguro payment provider, which encrypts the card via a script in javascript.

The documentation says 2 steps in order to encrypt a credit card:
https://dev.pagseguro.uol.com.br/reference/charge-encrypted

1. Add the following script in html (which I did in index.html)

```
<script src="https://assets.pagseguro.com.br/checkout-sdk-js/rc/dist/browser/pagseguro.min.js"></script>
```

2. Run the following method

```
var card = PagSeguro.encryptCard({
  publicKey: "MINHA_CHAVE_PUBLICA",
  holder: "Nome Sobrenome",
  number: "4242424242424242",
  expMonth: "12",
  expYear: "2030",
  securityCode: "123"
});
var encrypted = card.encryptedCard;
```

I'm using js package in order to run the script in my dart code via 'callmethod', and it works when I call scripts without arguments. However, when I put arguments, I'm getting a response saying my arguments are invalid/missing.

Here is my code:

```
import 'dart:js' as js;

var PagSeguro = js.JsObject.fromBrowserObject(js.context["PagSeguro"]);

js.JsObject card = PagSeguro.callMethod("encryptCard", [
//arguments being passed as a Map in index 0 of a List
      {
        "publicKey": publicKey,
        "holder": holder,
      "number": number,
      "expMonth": expMonth,
      "expYear": expYear,
      "securityCode": securityCode
      }
    ]);
```

Regardless of what I put in the arguments, the method is retuning error saying:

```
{errors: [{code: INVALID_NUMBER, message: invalid card `number`}, {code: INVALID_EXPIRATION_MONTH, message: invalid field `expMonth`. You must pass a value between 1 and 12}, {code: INVALID_EXPIRATION_YEAR, message: invalid field `expYear`. You must pass a value between 1900 and 2099}, {code: INVALID_HOLDER, message: invalid `holder`}], encryptedCard: null, hasErrors: true}
```

How can I properly pass the arguments via 'callmethod' in such a way javascript understands?

Answer (score 0):

```
var pagSeguro = js.JsObject.fromBrowserObject(js.context["PagSeguro"]);

var card = await pagSeguro.callMethod("encryptCard", [
```

//arguments being passed as a Map in index 0 of a List
js.JsObject.jsify({
"publicKey": publicKey,
"holder": holder,
"number": number,
"expMonth": expMonth,
"expYear": expYear,
"securityCode": securityCode
})
]);
print(card["encryptedCard"]);
window.console.log(card);

Comment: this is work -- js.JsObject.jsify({ "publicKey": publicKey, "holder": holder, "number": number, "expMonth": expMonth, "expYear": expYear, "securityCode": securityCode }

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).